# Custom Component for a switch with (OFF-PENDING-ON) State: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, setstate

I have this situation where a three state switch needs to be implemented. The switch should have three states for toggling i.e. OFF,PENDING and ON respectively.

I have tried my best of developing  a switch with ON/OFF. Been struggling with addition of "PENDING" state. Can someone help me with this?

I am trying to implement the following switch:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1WSN.png

Here is the link to the sandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-currying-rg6h5

Also below is the code for the same:

### App Component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isChecked: false
    };
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({ isChecked: !this.state.isChecked });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("switch value", this.state.isChecked);
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <label>
            <input
              checked={this.state.isChecked}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              className="switch"
              type="checkbox"
            />
            <div>
              <div />
            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"].switch {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"].switch + div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
  transition-property: background-color, box-shadow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"].switch + div {
  width: 94px;
  height: 48px;
}

input[type="checkbox"].switch:checked + div {
  background-color: #57bb00;
}

input[type="checkbox"].switch + div > div {
  float: left;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform, background-color;
  transition-property: transform, background-color;
  pointer-events: none;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

input[type="checkbox"].switch:checked + div > div {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(46px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(46px, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: For sure you cannot use a boolean as the state for this case. Now what you plan to use? a state holding string, digit, array with 3 items ....?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi May be a state with array that holds values [ENABLED,PENDING,DISABLED] !

Comment: Now the other problem is the concept of toggle, which is a two-state component, I recommend using something like [range slider](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_rangeslider)

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Would you help me out with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you want a checkbox that first checked -> unchecked it doesn't finish but is being pending until some timeout -> the checkbox is finally unchecked and the same happen the other way around when being unchecked and you want to check it.

you need two state, one for the checkbox state and the other for the pending state (two booleans) and you need to defer the event of checking the checkbox (checking it in an asynchronous manner)

here's a link to see what I means or read the code immediately
https://codepen.io/lalosh/project/editor/XVPbpW

```js
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      checkboxState: true,
      pending: false,
    }

    this.handleCheckboxChange = this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this);

  }

  handleCheckboxChange(event){
    this.setState({ pending: true });

    //because normally you cannot access event in an async manner unless you do this
    event.persist();

    setTimeout(() => {

      this.setState(state => ({ 
        checkboxState: !state.checkboxState,
        pending: false
      }));

    }, 2000)
  }

  render(){
    return (<div>
      {this.state.pending ? "I am pending" : ""}
      <br/>

      three state checkbox 

      <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkboxState} onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}/> checkMeIn

      </div>)
  }
}

export default App;
```

Please test it (copy paste to some file and run it) and tell me of the result.

Comment: Yes that adds an interval and adds "I am Pending" when it goes a transition from "checked" to "unchecked" and vice versa. But all I want is a state with three values "ON,Pending,OFF" . Like when I submit I need to pass any of the values to the server

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/2Lxt4bo8/5/   . But in a react way with proper state values

Comment: I edited my example
https://codepen.io/lalosh/project/editor/XVPbpW I hope it match what you want as a three state checkbox

Comment: what you post as in jsfiddle has different requirement than this question of three state checkbox and can be implemented easily with three input and one state var, I think.

Comment: May be if we could use three radio buttons and set the state accordingly (just as in jsfiddle.net/2Lxt4bo8/5) , Will it solve?

Comment: yes it can, but it will not be one checkbox anymore.

Comment: Would you help me with that? Like three radio buttons (just like in jsfiddle), I shoud be able to get the state value on change

Comment: here you go https://codepen.io/lalosh/project/editor/XVPbpW check it out

Comment: Thanks much . Guess you have not added the css part mentioned in http://jsfiddle.net/2Lxt4bo8/5/

Comment: Sorry, no I made the bare minimum React.js example and you can add what you want as you want